# Scraping large amount of Google Scholar pages with url

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, captcha, google-scholar

I'm trying to get full author list of all publications from an author on Google scholar using BeautifulSoup. Since the home page for the author only has a truncated list of authors for each paper, I have to open the link of the paper to get full list. As a result, I ran into CAPTCHA every few attempts.

Is there a way to avoid CAPTCHA (e.g. pause for 3 secs after every request)? Or make the original Google Scholar profile page to show full author list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently I faced similar issue. I at least eased my collection process with an easy workaround by implementing a *random* and *rather longlasting* sleep like this:

```
import time
import numpy as np

time.sleep((30-5)*np.random.random()+5) #from 5 to 30 seconds
```

If you have enough time (let's say launch your parser at night), you can make even bigger pause (3+ times bigger) to assure you won't get captcha.

Furthermore, you can randomly change `user-agent`s in your requests to site, that will mask you even more.

Comment: And randomly change proxies.